# Blackboard bold characters

Tags: fonts, bold, blackboard

The blackboard bold font in the AMSFonts package only has capital letters.  I sometimes wish to use a blackboard bold "1", for which I can use `\usepackage{bbold}`. But this changes the entire blackboard bold font, and I like the original AMSFonts versions of the capital letters better.  Is there a simple way for me to get `\mathbb{1}` from one package and the blackboard bold capitals from another?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question (how to use `bbold` with AMS's black board bold characters). I believe that would require some TeX incantations.

A cheaper work around is to use either the package [`bbm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bbm-macros) or the package [`doublestroke`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doublestroke). The former defines the `\mathbbm` command and the latter uses the `\mathds` command, so they don't conflict with the AMS `\mathbb`. Also asthetically I prefer the `bbm` fonts over `bbold` since the latter is sans serif, which doesn't quite fit in right against the AMS serifed fonts.

Comment: That may not answer the question precisely as I asked it, but it tells me how to do what I want to do.  The sans serif issue is also my aesthetic complaint with the bbold font.

Comment: @MarkMeckes: Note that `\mathbbm` selects a Type 3 font whereas `\mathds` selects a Type 1 font.

Comment: @mhp please could you give a reference for what you mean by these font types? Is there a significant distinction?

Comment: @MorganRogers: the types refers to PostScript font types (see e.g. Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts and references there). In terms of the underlying technology (subset of PostScript used, and features supported) there are some differences. From the user's point of view the main issue is that some software do not support the use of Type 3 fonts. This can be an issue when, for example, preparing a PDF manuscript for submission to a journal, whose online processing system cannot deal with Type 3 fonts.

Answer (score 39):

I had the same question about a year ago. I came up with the following solution, which seems a bit cleaner that Juan's "hack":

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbold}{bbold}
```

Then one can use `$\mathbbold{1}$` (and I store this, without the dollar signs, in the macro `\ind` since I use it as an indicator function).

Comment: I wanted to do this outside of math mode; however, when I try this, I get the error: `LaTeX Error: \prettytext allowed only in math mode.`

Answer (score 18):

You've already got a pretty good answer. Just in case you *really* wanted to use `amsmath` and `bbold`, the following TeX-hack seems to do the trick.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\makeatletter
\def\amsbb{\use@mathgroup \M@U \symAMSb}
\makeatother

\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{1}, \amsbb{X}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I don't *really* want to do that, but I may well find myself wanting to use a similar hack for a different purpose sometime.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to do what you want that leaves `\mathbb` using the AMS fonts.

```
\newcommand{\bbfamily}{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{bbold}\selectfont}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
```

You can then use `\mathbbold` for the bbold math fonts.

Comment: Could you maybe indicate in which way your answer differs from [the one given by @HendrikVogt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3260/5001)? Your answer and his are not the same, but do seem to rely on the same underlying machinery.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following format. You may also check this [link](https://programmer.group/solution-for-entering-blackboard-bold-numbers-in-latex.html) for various packages which offers different kind of solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize}
    \item $\mathbb{1}_X$
    \item $\mathbb{\Omega}$
    \item $\mathbb{\Delta}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Blackboard Characters]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The OP was already using `bbold`, and wanted to avoid it changing the whole blackboard bold font.