# Looking for \mathbb style $\Delta$ and $\nabla$

Tags: symbols, greek

I came across the following two symbols in an article:

[image]
[image]

The usual `\mathbb{\Delta}` or `\mathbb{\nabla}` aren't working. Can anybody say what package/command I should use to reproduce these?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I have not seen this symbols so far -- perhaps they aren't provided directly and have to be constructed with `\kern` etc.

Comment: What does it mean? For me it looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_pyramids

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: The famous Pyramid operators applied by aliens instead of `\Delta` and `\nabla^2` ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke The first is a certain metric, the second is a certain tangent vector called ambient gradient . They come from this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0434v1.pdf

Comment: See also: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mbboard

Comment: @Sayantan The notation in the linked article is very odd. See, e.g., Gromov-Prokhorov metric in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5464.pdf

Comment: @KolaB.: The integral symbols in the linked article are peculiar

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/blackboard-bold-variants-for-greek-letters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the definitions employed by the paper's author by downloading the [source file](https://arxiv.org/format/1208.0434v1) from arXiv.

Those two symbols are there defined as:

```
\newcommand{\DD}{\Delta\!\!\!\!\Delta}
\newcommand{\Grad}{\nabla\!\!\!\!\nabla}
```

Note that this might not be the best way to define symbols like those -- it's just the way used by the author -- and other answers here can provide better definitions.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible workaround if the symbols aren't available:

Use the relevant symbol, say `\Delta` with negative kerning, say, `\mkern-12u` and the same symbol again.

The kerning value is just a guess and can be changed of course.

The package `bbold` provides a blackboard letter symbol for `\Delta`, but this looks different and is probably not desired.

The `mbboard` package seems to define the symbols out of the box, but it is not on TeXLive, see [mbboard on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mbboard).

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbold}


\newcommand{\bbDelta}{%
  \Delta\mkern-12mu\Delta%
}

\newcommand{\bbNabla}{%
  \nabla\mkern-12mu\nabla%
}

\begin{document}

The symbol \verb!\mathbb{\Delta}!  $\mathbb{\Delta}$ is probably wrong. 


Some testing of symbols
\verb!\normalsize:!\normalsize

$\bbDelta$ and $\bbNabla$

\verb!\large:!\large

$\bbDelta$ and $\bbNabla$

\verb!\Large:!\Large

$\bbDelta$ and $\bbNabla$

\verb!\LARGE:!\LARGE

$\bbDelta$ and $\bbNabla$

\verb!\huge:!\huge

$\bbDelta$ and $\bbNabla$


\normalsize
\[
   \bbDelta \neq \bbNabla
\]


\end{document}


[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\def\dDelta{\upDelta\mkern-10mu\upDelta}
\def\dNabla{\nabla\mkern-10mu\nabla}
\begin{document}

\Huge$\dDelta$ and $\dNabla$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the bold characters use `\mbfDelta` and `\mbfnabla` instead.