# Blackboard bold capital Delta with Euler fonts

Tags: boldmath

I would like to draw a blackboard bold capital delta, but I would like to draw this while using the Euler package to get the Euler fonts.

I have tried both solutions mentioned in the first answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/blackboard-bold-variants-for-greek-letters#3474) but either they don't seem to work with capital delta or it is overwritten by the Euler package.

I also took a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314184/looking-for-mathbb-style-delta-and-nabla) but I am not satisfied with the solution -- the symbol has two peaks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathbbol}

\newcommand{\DD}{\Delta\!\!\!\Delta}

\begin{document}

     $\mathbbm{\Delta}$ 
     %Using mathbbm -- isn't math bold

     $\mathbb{\Delta}$ 
     %Using mathbbol -- still isn't math bold

     $\DD$ 
     %Hacky, and I dislike the two peaks

\end{document}
```

Comment: The following code `\newcommand{\Dd}{\Delta\!\!\!{\scalebox{0.7}{$\Delta$}}}` works okay, but it's kind of hacky and I find it hard to believe that nobody has wanted to do this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bbDelta}{{\mathpalette\bb@Delta\relax}}
\newcommand{\bb@Delta}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\Delta$}%
  \dimendef\Dht=6 \dimendef\Dwd=8
  \setlength{\Dwd}{\wd\z@}%
  \setlength{\Dht}{\ht\z@}%
  \begin{picture}(\Dwd,\Dht)
  \put(0,0){$\m@th#1\Delta$}
  \put(.42\Dwd,.7\Dht){\line(10,-26){.25\Dht}}
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

x$\Delta\bbDelta$ $\scriptstyle\Delta\bbDelta$

x$\bbDelta\Delta$ $\scriptstyle\bbDelta\Delta$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to take the capital Delta from Euler and the blackboard Delta from `mathbbol`, then you need to use something other than `\Delta` to access it as `\Delta` is redefined by `euler.sty`. This is pretty straightforward. Here I define a `\bbDelta` macro to parallel the `\bbdelta` one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}
\DeclareMathSymbol\bbDelta  \mathord{bbold}{"01}

\begin{document}

\[
  \bbDelta
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: access to blackboard Delta]