# How to use mathbbol only for greek and lowercase

Tags: fonts, blackboard

I would like to use the [mathbbol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathbbol?lang=en) for all blackboard fonts *that aren't already contained in the usual `\mathbb` command*: this includes lower case, greek (both lower and upper case) letters, digits, and more. But I still would like capital letters to work with the usual blackboard font (e.g. `\mathbb{E}`). I have tried to fiddle with the answers to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters) question for hours without success. Ideally, I would like to use `\mathbb` just for upper case letters, and something else (like `\mathbbm`) for everything else. Here is what I've tried:

1. `\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}`: this way I get the greek letters (`\mathbb{\gamma}`, `\bbgamma`), but the old commands `\mathbb{E}` are overwritten;
2. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3260/11123) answer works fine for lower case letters (and does not overwrite the upper case blackboard ones), but the greek ones (e.g. `\bbdelta`) are not defined;
3. In mathbbol's readme file it suggests to load the package before amsmath and amsfonts, but this does not prevent the `\mathbb` command from being overwritten.
4. Define the symbols one by one using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360299/11123) answer; this is my solution for now, but it is far from ideal.

There has got to be a really easy workaround, but I simply do not know enough about LaTeX fonts to find it. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho they don't fit. It would be better to take all from mathbbol. But if you want it, you only need to reset mathbb:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}


\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbm}{bbold}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}%

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{ABCD} \mathbbm{abcdelki} \bbalpha \bbomega $ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. I take your point about the two fonts not fitting well, but mathbbol upper case letters are just too ugly...