# \mathbb gives strange results when using numbers

Tags: errors, symbols, mathbb

LaTeX command `\mathbb` gives strange results when using numbers.

For example, `\mathbb{1}` prints an unintended symbol.

There was a previous question on this topic whose solution involved using the `\mathbbol` package, but it doesn't seem to be working anymore. The solution posted originates a compilation error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and the link to the post you mentioned.

Comment: `\mathbb{1}` has never worked for printing a 1; what “posted solution” are you referring to?

Comment: @egreg -- there *have* been some blackboard bold fonts that contained digits as well as letters, and if they were "properly" organized, `\mathbb{1}` would produce a double-line "1".  but the "usual" (original, old) blackboard bold fonts had neither digits nor lowercase.  still, we need to know what previous question is being referred to to make sense of this question.

Comment: @egreg -- The answer I meant was [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384265/how-to-use-mathbbol-only-for-greek-and-lowercase). I tried it but my Miktex engine complained about not finding specific fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters). Basically just declare package "bbm" and use command "\mathbbm{1}".

Comment: `mathbbm` is not `mathbb`.