# Latex: How to produce a "Black Board Bold" Epsilon Symbol

Tags: symbols

[image]

I have been unable to find a latex command for a black board bold variant of epsilon. Is there an easy way to produce this symbol?

I have drawn a rough outline of the kind of thing I have in mind.

Comment: There’s one in `mbboard`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/blackboard-bold-variants-for-greek-letters

Comment: There's also one in `bbold`.