# How do I make a blackboard 1?

Tags: math-mode, blackboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blackboard bold characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters)

I want to make a blackboard "1" character to show an indicator variable, but `$\mathbb{1}$` doesn't work.  How do I do it?

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters/3260).

Comment: Better answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`symbols` (see [“How to look up a math symbol?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)) lists the following packages: `bbold`, `mathbbol`, `mbboard`, `bbm` (with `\mathbbm`, `\mathbbmss` or `\mathbbmtt`) and `dsfont` (with or without the `sans` option).

Alternatively, XeTeX+`unicode math` supports it directly.