# Typesetting the Identity Operator for txfonts

Tags: fonts, symbols, characters

I use the `txfonts` package in my document for fonts.  However, I am at a loss as to how to produce the identity operator, which looks like a blackboard bold 1.  Now,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document} 
\[
\mathbb{1}
\]
\end{document}
```

produces basically what I am looking for.  However, this also replaces all of the other `\mathbb` characters with those from the bbold package.  Is there a better way to obtain the identity operator symbol?

Comment: Have you tried the bbm package? (so using  \mathbbm{1})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [`txfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) and [`bbold`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bbold) declare the math alphabet `\mathbb`, therefore the first definition is overwritten by the package which is loaded last. If you generally want to use the `txfonts` blackboard bold symbols, you can declare a new math alphabet `\mathbbold` *instead* of loading `bbold`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}    
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbbold{1}, % from bbold
\mathbb{N} % from txfonts
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem really is when you use both `\usepackage{bbold}` and `\usepackage{amsfont}` (or `\usepackage{mathsymb}`) together: depending which one is last, you get different `\mathbb` fonts.

A workaround is to use the http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/help/Catalogue/entries/mathbbol.html package: a working example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
  \[                                                                              
  \Eins \ne \mathbb{1}                                                            
  \]
\end{document}
```

P.S. `\mathbbm` also works, but you use a slightly different font, which might be OK or not OK depending on your taste.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the bbm package. So you can produce a blackboard 1 by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document} 
$\mathbbm{1}$
\end{document}
```

Here are some other answers that go a bit deeper :

[How do I make a blackboard 1?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/how-do-i-make-a-blackboard-1),

[Blackboard bold characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters)