# How do you get \mathbb{1} to work (characteristic function of a set)?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I am trying to get the digit one printed the `\mathbb{}` font in math mode, however the command

```
\mathbb{1}
```

outputs some rubbish. I certainly saw the character I am after in some pdf's generated from latex, hence my question: how do you get it to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a blackboard 1?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/how-do-i-make-a-blackboard-1)

Comment: The `\mathbb` provided as part of the `amsfonts` package does not provide numerals. Section 3.3 of [`amsfonts`' documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsfonts/amsfndoc.pdf) states that the `\mathbb` command it provides uses the `msbm` font and so supports only uppercase letters: no lowercase, no numerals.

Comment: note that using any package that provides a complete blackboard bold font overrides the `\mathbb` provided by `amsfonts`.  if you wish to replace only the digit "1", you can use the method described here: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: off topic: After years reading math texts, I think that the most common notation for the characteristic function of a set `$A$` is `\chi_A`.

Comment: How come "they" don't fix this? Is there a fundamental problem?

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Since `\mathbb` doesn't support digits (with `amssymb` or `txfonts`) you may use [`bbm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bbm):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathbbm{1} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: bbm example]

or `dsfont` in the [`doublestroke`](https://ctan.org/pkg/doublestroke) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathds{1} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: dsfont example]

Comment: I guess `\mathbbm{1}`is the best in terms of consistency with `\mathbb`.

Comment: You can also add `\newcommand{\1}[1]{\mathds{1}\left[#1\right]}` to your preamble to create a quick indicator function that handles what you wanna put inside it.

Comment: I get the error: File bbm.sty not found. Also File dsfont.sty not found.

Answer (score 59):

Playing some necromancy here, the answer looks very different in 2021.  I especially advise **against** using `bbm`, as the accepted answer suggests, since the old-fashioned font format it loads will come out pixelated in a PDF, and nobody prints DVIs out on paper any more.

I’d recommend using `unicode-math` in LuaTeX when you can, and legacy fonts when you have to.  [Nearly all OpenType math fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) support `\mathbb{1}` and `\Bbbone` out of the box.  Few if any come with a bold version that supports `\boldsymbol{\mathbb{1}}`, but you can fake it if you need it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}[
  version=bold,
  FakeBold = 1.2 ]

\begin{document}
\[ \mathbb{1} \boldsymbol{\mathbb{1}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern sample]

If your publisher still requires you to use PDFTeX, or you should wish to, the `mathalpha` package provides a consistent interface for loading and scaling math alphabets, including blackboard bold and bold blackboard bold.  Here are the options that ship with TeX Live and at least partially work:

(Note that you do not need to define `\Bbbbone` this way in your own document!  I put this in the template to simplify testing.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bb=dsserif]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{bm}

\pagestyle{empty}
    
\newcommand\Bbbbone{%
  \ifdefined\mathbbb%
    \mathbbb{1}%
  \else%
    \boldsymbol{\mathbb{1}}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathbb{1} \Bbbbone
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: dsserif sample]

The `dsserif` alphabet is the only free one I know of that supports both blackboard-bold and bold-blackboard-bold digits in Type-1 format, and that a package can load without changing your other fonts.  You will probably want to scale this to match your math font, with the `bbscaled=` package option.

With `bb=pazo` instead of `bb=dsserif`:

[image: Pazo sample]

With `bb=fourier`:

[image: Fourier sample]

With `bb=esstix`:

[image: Esstix sample]

With `bb=boondox`:

[image: Boondox sample]

There are other legacy packages not available through `mathalpha` (as of February 2021).  Here are some of the more important ones that have not already been mentioned.

The `cmathbb` package is an attractive outline font based on Computer Modern bold.

[image: cmathbb sample]

With `\usepackage[varbb]{newtxmath}`, you get the same alphabet as in Xovee’s answer, but replacing the standard `\mathbb`:

[image: Newtx varbb sample]

There is a similar option for `newpxmath` (although this is incompatible with `bm`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[varbb]{newpxmath}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand\Bbbbone{%
  \ifdefined\mathbbb%
    \mathbbb{1}%
  \else%
    \boldsymbol{\mathbb{1}}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathbb{1} \Bbbbone
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Newpx varbb sample]

There is yet another blackboard bold alphabet available through `newtxmath` and `newpxmath`, with the `vvarbb` package option:

[image: Newpx vvarbb sample]

The `stix` and `stix2` packages load an alphabet similar to `boondox`.  (Which is a fork of the STIX fonts.)  Here is what you get with `\usepackage{stix2}` instead of `mathalpha`:

[image: STIX 2 font sample]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, using unicode-math ruins the other mathbb letters. Is there any way of keeping the standard mathbb while using unicode-math?
PS: I keep coming back to this question since I haven't still a satisfactory answer

Comment: @Manza yes, you can `\DeclareMathAlphabet` with the AMS bb font. Just use another name than `\mathbb`.

Comment: @Manza Or load an Opentype font whose `\mathbb` you like better with `range=bb`.

Comment: Btw, the newer version of NewCM provides blackboard math in CM style, similar to dsfont. It contains numbera as well.

Answer (score 25):

Another option is to use `bbold` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathbb{1} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: bbold example]

Though it ruins the letters.

Answer (score 21):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this, but you can use the `unicode-math` package. Note that you need Xe(La)TeX or LuaLaTeX to use this package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    $\mathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps because it can't be used with pdflatex: "Package unicode-math Error: Cannot be run with pdfLaTeX!"

Comment: Only this worked for me with LuaLaTex.

Answer (score 15):

A new solution: use `newtxmath` package.

With code:

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}

$\vmathbb{ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWSYZ}$

$\vmathbb{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

$\vmathbb{0123456789}$
```

which results:

[image]

Also, this solution is compatible with the ACM Template's whitelist restriction, since there're no need to import other packages, the document class `asmart` already imported the `newtxmath`.

Here's the document of the `newtxmath`: http://ctan.mirror.colo-serv.net/fonts/newtx/doc/newtxdoc.pdf

Comment: Why the lower case letters (except k) are not supported?

Comment: This also works with the `newpxmath` package, could you update you answer? :)

Comment: @HoseinRahnama now it supports lower letters

Comment: @G.J I have updated the answer! Thank you for remind.

Answer (score 4):

Like user41766 said, using `bbold` is a good idea (the best imho if `unicode-math` isn't an option), but it would "ruin" the other letters. You can solve this issue by declaring a new alphabet, importing `\mathbb` from `bbold` into your own math alphabet, like was suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509177/blackboard-type-omega-symbol):

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathmybb}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathmybb{1}}
```

Note that you can then use `\mathmybb` in any other situation and name it any other way you please.

[image: img]

Edit: This question is also nicely dealt with [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566794/232266), where this compact solution can be found to avoid creating a whole math alphabet:

```
\newcommand*{\boldone}{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}}
```

Comment: Thank you!  the above `\boldone` plus the `{bbold}` package seem nice to me.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
\usepackage{mathbbol}

+\mathbb{1}+
```

Actually, I'm using LyX, so I put `\usepackage` in the preamble and then simply used `\mathbb` with a 1 inside a formula box. It still displays as `rubbish' but renders fine as PDF.

If you don't like the discordance in LyX, you can say something like

```
\def\bbone{\mathbb{1}}
```

in the preamble, and then use `\bbone` in your document, or variants on this theme.

My 2c.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all Unicode math fonts have the character U+1D7D9 with TeX control sequence `\Bbbone` which looks like this: .

If you have Unicode math font loaded then you can use `\Bbbone` or directly . For example, in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]  % loads Unicode math

$\Bbbone$ or $$.   
\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}        
\usepackage{anyfontsize}         
% For documents in 10pt, 11pt or 12pt     
% \def\one{\mbox{1\hspace{-3.85pt}\fontsize{11}{14.4}\selectfont\textrm{1}}} % 10pt    
\def\one{\mbox{1\hspace{-4.25pt}\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont\textrm{1}}} % 11pt    
% \def\one{\mbox{1\hspace{-4.75pt}\fontsize{13}{14.4}\selectfont\textrm{1}}} % 12pt    
\begin{document}    
You can use either $\one$ or $\one\{A\}$ or $\one_{A}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do note that `\rm` is considered deprecated for a LaTeX document. It also doesn't take an argument; instead, it acts as a switch. Thus, instead of `\rm{\fontsize{11}{14.4}\selectfont 1}`, do write `\fontsize{11}{14.4}\selectfont\textrm{1}`. Also, is there something that can be done to produce less of an overlap/clash between the tops of the two `1` numeral?

Comment: The correct metrics depend on the font and font family, I guess. I typeset most of my documents with \usepackage{mathptmx}, a Times like font, and the code given works just perfectly. Adjust the argument of \hspace accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

With `unicode-math` (requires LuaTeX or XeTex), you can change the font of only the `\mathbb{}` numbers to, e.g., "Latin Modern Math", which does include them:

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range=bb/{num}]
```