# How to include LaTeX package in R Markdown?

Tags: r, knitr, markdown, rstudio

I am writing a report with Rmd in RStudio via knitr package.

I want to write a indicator variable symbol in the report, like [How do you get \mathbb{1} to work (characteristic function of a set)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set).

The line `\usepackage{bbm}` should be included according to the answer.

I tried first

```
$$
\usepackage{bbm}
y_{ij} = b_{ij} + \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}
$$
```

But the program cannot interpret  `\usepackage{bbm}`.

Comment: It would be great to see a full code in your post. My general advice is that `\usepackage{bbm}` belongs to the preamble of the document, not to the document body. Meaning, move this part above `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Malipivo This is a question about R Markdown, and I believe it belongs to StackOverflow instead of TeX.SE.

Answer (score 130):

I think this is the easiest option!

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{bbm}
output:
    pdf_document
---
```

*(Edited to have three, instead of four, hyphens to open and close the YAML front-matter)*

Comment: This worked more readily than the other answer, which could not find the path to tex.

Answer (score 42):

As per [this page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) on the R Markdown website, you can add whatever you want to the preamble via the `in-header` option in the YAML header; e.g.,

```
----
title: "Titre"
date: Fecha
output:
    pdf_document:
        includes:
            in_header: mystyles.sty
----
```

In `mystyles.sty`, located in the same directory as the .Rmd, you could have a whole list of additional things to add to the preamble of document, e.g.:

```
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{expex}
```

Etc. The contents of `mystyles.sty` are then pasted into the LaTeX preamble; check out the default LaTeX template used [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex#L142) to see where precisely in the preamble they are included.

As a minimal example I tested an Rmd document with the header from above including the .sty from above and having the following in the body of the document:

```
$$ y_{ij} = b_{ij} + \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} $$

Test test $\mathbb{1}$ test.
```

Comment: I believe that this code `$\mathbb{1}$` should in fact be `$\mathbbm{1}$`, in order to utilise the `bbm` package, as described on page 1 [here](http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/bbm.pdf). Using `$\mathbbm{1}$` gives me the correct symbol, whereas `$\mathbb{1}$` gives me a "not \Vdash" amssymb symbol.

Answer (score 16):

As of rmarkdown [version 1.4](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/NEWS.md) it has been possible to use the `extra_dependencies` parameter to list a character vector of LaTeX packages. This is useful if you need to load multiple packages:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["bbm", "threeparttable"]
---
```

If you need to specify options when loading the package, you can add a second-level to the list and provide the options as a list:

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies:
      hyperref: ["unicode=true", "breaklinks=true"]
      lmodern: null
```

Comment: Do you know why this code works when the output is `pdf_document` but not when it is `html_document`? (I asked about this problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722994/inconsistent-processing-of-yaml-lists-in-r-markdown-documents-related-to-loadin.)

Comment: this option is not present for `beamer_presentation`, which is odd since beamer should be a subset of `pdf_document` family. ```Error in (function (toc = FALSE, slide_level = NULL, number_sections = FALSE,  : 
  unused argument (extra_dependencies = "booktabs")
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> create_output_format -> do.call
Execution halted```