# "LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble" even though all directives before begin directive

Tags: pandoc, preamble, markdown

In the following simplified version of a `markdown` doc intended for `pandoc`/`latex`  generation to `pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\begin{document}

## Custom F1 Score For Scoring of Graph Matching

### Overview

The `F1 Score` is intended to compare two sets:

- Truth Set
- Actuals Set

Its calculation is:

$$F_{\beta} = (1 + \beta^2) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{precision_k} \cdot \mathrm{recall_k^2}}{(\beta^2 \cdot \mathrm{precision_k}) + \mathrm{recall_k}}$$


\end{document}
```

Notice that all of the `preamble` directives happen before the 
    `begin{document}`

The *pdf* is generated via `pandoc`:

```
    $pandoc  -V fontsize=9pt --pdf-engine xelatex -V 
geometry:"left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm" -o myDoc.pdf myDoc.md
```

The following error is produced:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.60 \documentclass
```

What is incorrect here for bringing in a mathsy font?

Comment: In markdown you need a YAML header, not `\documentclass{article}`. Use something like `- header-includes: -\usepackage{unicode-math} -\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola} -\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}`. See, for example, [How to include LaTeX package in R Markdown?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171711/5764)

Comment: @Werner - ah ya .. I have other docs doing that  and will go copy and paste from them. Pls make this an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conversion of a markdown document places content within a YAML header within the preamble. However, since there is no YAML header specified, the contents is assumed to form part of the regular document body. As such, `\documentclass` (and the rest) ends up after `\begin{document}` and not in the preamble. Hence, the error "Can be used only in preamble" and pointing to `\documentclass`...

You'll need something like this:

```
---
title: "Some title"
author: "Some author"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{unicode-math}
  - \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
  - \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
output:
    pdf_document
---

## Custom F1 Score For Scoring of Graph Matching

### Overview

...
```

Also see [How to include LaTeX package in R Markdown?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171711/5764)

Comment: ya i forgot to add that `yaml` header.

Comment: In newer versions of pandoc you can set the fonts directly: `mainfont: 'TeX Gyre Schola'` and `mathfont: 'TeX Gyre Schola Math'`, cf.  https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have two problems.

The first is that you need to escape the `#` symbols (i.e. like `\#`).

The second is your pandoc command.  You need to add `--from latex` to it, like this:

```
pandoc  -V fontsize=9pt --from latex --pdf-engine xelatex -V geometry:"left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm" -o myDoc.pdf myDoc.md
```

I'm not entirely sure why you are using LaTeX code in a Markdown file, however.  When I change your command to:

```
pandoc  -V fontsize=9pt --pdf-engine xelatex -V geometry:"left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm" -o myDoc.pdf myDoc.tex
```

And the file from `.md` to `.tex`, it also fixes the problem.  It seems more natural to just keep it as a `.tex` file, because it *is* a `.tex` file.  Not sure if I misunderstood something?

Comment: "escape the #"   *huh* ?  this absolutely is `markdown`. I have truncated a couple hundred line markdown file to show just the `tex` related portion of it.

Comment: @javadba it was difficult to tell.  Looked like TeX, but you were saying Markdown, so I was a little confused what you were aiming for.  I decided to go the route of the document provided, whereas Werner went the route that you said in your post :)  Anyhow, glad it worked out with his answer.