# How to add Latex packages to markdown?

Tags: markdown

I am writing some text with Markdown on the Jupyter notebook. But I am not able to import some Latex packages to the notebook. I tried to follow [How to include LaTeX package in R Markdown?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown). I tried to include the `mathtools` package, but it does not work.

With

```
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{mathtools}
output:
    pdf_document
```

I am still not able to call commands like `$\xrightarrow[\text{sample text}]$` on Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You cannot write with square brackets `[]` in your math formula. Replace with `{}` and your code works.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show us a minimal working example. including documentclass and etc.

Comment: Before downvoting, kindly note this is `markdown`, which is converted to `LaTeX` to render the `pdf`. As such, it begins with a `YAML` header, not `\documentclass`. The OP has given enough code and information to identify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Don't use square brackets `[]` in your math expression. Use braces `{}` only. You wrote: `$\xrightarrow[\text{sample text}]$`. It should be: `$\xrightarrow{\text{sample text}}$`.

Edit: Updated to show the use of `\Bracket` and `\Set` from the `braket` package.

[image]

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{mathtools}
  - \usepackage{braket}
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\hrule <!-- draw a horizontal line -->

We can _write_ in **markdown** and add content that uses ``LaTeX`` syntax and \LaTeX\ packages to format our document.

## Using ``mathtools`` package

$\xrightarrow{\text{sample text}}$

<br> <!-- add space, like \bigskip % - this is a comment -->

## Using ``array``, ``booktabs`` and ``braket`` packages

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\footnotesize}r>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}@{}}
\toprule 
  \verb+\Braket{ \phi | \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} | \psi }+ & \Braket{ \phi | \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} | \psi } \\
  \verb+\Set{ x\in\mathbf{R}^2 | 0<{|x|}<5 }+                     & \Set{ x\in\mathbf{R}^2 | 0<{|x|}<5 }                    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

## We can do math

```{r math}
result <- 1 + 2
result
```
````

Comment: For additional packages, may I just add them right under - \usepackage{mathtools}? For example, I add - \usepackage{braket} right under - \usepackage{mathtools}, but it seems it does not take effect. I still cannot call $\bra{aa}$
 etc..

Comment: Yes, just add any additional packages you require under `header-includes`. See the update.

Comment: I copied and pasted your template into jupyter notebook, but it doesn't work for me.