# How to get \mathbbm{1} to work?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I am somewhat a new user to the TeX world. So, hopefully my question is not out of scope.

I saw it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set) how to create an indicator function with mathbbm package. So, I ran this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathbbm{1} \]
\end{document}
```

But it does not produce any results at all:

!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file bbm10): Font bbm10 at 600 not
found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

You can see a log file here: [log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dtmsugq5chthz0/testing.log?dl=0)

Any suggestions of what the problem could be?

Comment: Your example works fine for me and the part of the log that you quote is normal. Show the rest until the end of the log-file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! With my MikTeX 64-bit installation, recent version, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the clarification. I added the log file.

Comment: Looks like you didn't install all fonts.  What system?

Comment: Hm. You have the sty and the tfm. Do you have bbm10.mf in `.../texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/bbm/bbm10.mf`? If yes it looks as if your system can't trigger mktexpk to generate the pk but I can't tell you why.