# Problem with bbm font => Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Tags: fonts, texlive-2018

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
$\mathbbm{1}$
\end{document}
```

The log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.8.28)  28 AUG 2018 13:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls
Document Class: elsarticle 2018/06/08, 3.0: Elsevier Ltd
\@bls=\dimen102
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen103
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen104
\Gin@req@width=\dimen105
)
\c@tnote=\count88
\c@fnote=\count89
\c@cnote=\count90
\c@ead=\count91
\c@author=\count92
\@eadauthor=\toks15
\c@affn=\count93
\absbox=\box26
\keybox=\box27
\Columnwidth=\dimen106
\space@left=\dimen107
\els@boxa=\box28
\els@boxb=\box29
\leftMargin=\dimen108
\@enLab=\toks16
\@sep=\skip43
\@@sep=\skip44

(./test.spl) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip45
\bibsep=\skip46
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count94
)
\splwrite=\write3
\openout3 = `test.spl'.

\appnamewidth=\dimen109
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty
Package: bbm 1999/03/15 V 1.2 provides fonts for set symbols - TH
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbbm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/bbm/m/n --> U/bbm/bx/n on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbbmss' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/bbmss/m/n --> U/bbmss/bx/n on input line 35.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2018/06/05 3.22 The Babel package

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2018/06/05 3.22 Babel switching mechanism
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2018/06/05 3.22 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count95
\U@D=\dimen110

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count96
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count97
\scratchdimen=\dimen111
\scratchbox=\box30
\nofMPsegments=\count98
\nofMParguments=\count99
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count100
\MPscratchDim=\dimen112
\MPnumerator=\count101
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count102
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+bbm on input line 7.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/ubbm.fd
File: ubbm.fd 1999/03/15 V 1.2 Font definition for bbm font - TH
) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test
.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2757 strings out of 492642
 36483 string characters out of 6129384
 106475 words of memory out of 5000000
 6622 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4798 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,4n,30p,271b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1
.enc}
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file bbm10): Font bbm10 at 600 not
 found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have reinstalled the complete system and checked whether the `bbm` packages are also installed.

Comment: Quite strange. It works for me with an up to date TeXLive 2018 (an with a TeXLive 2015 too). I did a diff of the logs and they are basically equal (except in the part that you have the error). Desperate attempt: download [this file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01547426561417902162) and place it in `/home/<your-username>/.texlive2018/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm/` and try again...

Comment: `mv bbm10.600pk /home/mm/.texlive2018/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm` yields `mv: rename bbm10.600pk to /home/mm/.texlive2018/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm: No such file or directory`

Comment: You are missing one slash to indicate that `bbm` is a directory. Try `mv bbm10.600pk /home/mm/.texlive2018/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm/` or, more clearly `mv bbm10.600pk /home/mm/.texlive2018/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm/bbm10.600pk`.

Comment: Works fine here, also with (not quite current) TL 2018. How did you install TL? Put `\listfiles` before the class line and post the file list you get in the output/log for comparison.

Comment: Crosspost in German: https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/22721

Comment: What happens if you run `\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapfile{} \begin{document} \Huge Hallo \end{document}` . Do you get a similar error?

Comment: This just got bumped in 2022. [Someone coming here today might want to use this updated answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set/583600#583600)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem related with to get the `Arabic numerals` to be in `bb` font, then try with `dsfont.sty` instead of `bbm` and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}
$\mathds{1}$
\end{document}
```

Also `cmathbb.sty` also an another option...