# How to write "conditional one" in Latex

Tags: math-mode

I want to write a "conditional one" in Latex but I don't know the precise name. It is a one with a double vertical dash that is equal to 1 if a condition is satisfied and 0 otherwise (a kind of Kronecker delta).

Could someone tell what is the name of this symbol and how to write it in Latex ?

Comment: Have you tried `\mathbb{1}` (with appropriate fonts loaded)?

Comment: Isn't the just the indicator function? Often just written as a bold 1 as many fonts are missing a double stroke 1.

Comment: @TeXnician What do you mean by appropriate fonts ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set

Comment: @MysteryGuy not all fonts that provide double stroke letters provide it for all letters and numbers, some only for A-Z, some for A-Z + 1 etc. It all depends on the base setup you are using (of which you provided no information)