# How to add this mathematical sign in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Following is an equation (taken from Reinforcement Learning field). How can I add the first sign (like 1) in LaTeX and what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set

Comment: Thanks! What is the official name of the function?

Comment: The font style is called Blackboard bold or double struck, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold. From that page about the : "Often represents, in set theory, the top element of a forcing poset, or occasionally the identity matrix in a matrix ring. Also used for the indicator function and the unit step function, and for the identity operator or identity matrix." The linked question calls it "characteristic function of a set".