# How to typeset indicator function in acmart class

Tags: libertine, acmart

I want to write a special `1` character to denote the [Indicator Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).
The class loads Libertine fonts and I think there is no option to override them.
See [Section 3.8 of documentation](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf).

The following minimal example types all `1` values the same way.

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{dsfont,bm,bbm}

\begin{document}
$\mathds{1},\bm{1},\mathbb{1},\mathbbm{1},{1}$
\end{document}
```

The reason as I see it, is because there is no double stroke or bold `1` in Libertine fonts. Is there any alternative to write  any specially typed `1`. I can also use the `I` character but since I already use `I` to denote different things I would like to avoid causing confusion.

Update:
It seems that when I compile with `XeLaTeX` MWE works as expected except for `\mathbb` macro, but not when I compile with `LaTeX` or `PDFLaTeX`. What could be the issue in this case?

Comment: If I run your MWE (on TL2019) I get 4 different tokens of `1`, although `\mathbb{1}` produces `⊮`, which might be related to this issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set

Comment: I will update my question but it seems when I compile with XeLaTeX I also get different tokens.