# How can I successfully compile $\mathbb{5}$?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, mathbb

I am a regular Overleaf user. I wanted to compile `$\mathbb{5}$`. I can do it for `$\mathbb{1}$`(Or like `$\mathbb{1}$`). I have read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set).

I have used this set of packages alongside the other necessary packages.

```
\usepackage{bbm} %%(The \mathbb{} effect for 1 only)
%\usepackage{newtxmath} %%(The \mathbb{} effect for digits)
%\usepackage{unicode-math} %(Only works with LuaLatex)
\usepackage{dsfont}
```

The only time I have a positive return is the case when I use `usepackage{newtxmath}`. But when I use the package, it ruins the whole text of the pdf.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, ```\mathds{5}``` is not working for me.

Comment: With [cmathbb package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmathbb) in the new version of TexLive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the double struck from stix2, just taking enough from stix2.sty to define the one font not change the whole setup.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\stixbb}{LS1}{stix2bb}   {m} {n}
\begin{document}

[$\stixbb{12345}+12345$]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I use ```\documentclass{amsart}```. There will be no issues, right?

Comment: font setup in amsart is essentially same as article+amsmath so should be fine @RalphClausen

Comment: Thanks! @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 3):

This works out of the box in `unicode-math`.  The package also supports `\Bbbfive` and the Unicode character .