# Import \mathbb{1} character from the unicode-math package

Tags: symbols, amsmath, unicode-math, blackboard

I'd like to import only the \mathbb{1} character from the unicode-math package into a document using the standard Computer Modern font along with the amsmath and amssymb packages, but I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be tremendously welcome!

Note: I would prefer NOT to use the bbol, mathbbold, bbm, ... packages. The only package I've encountered so far that provides a nice rendering of the character I'm looking for is unicode-math.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please explain what engine you are using. If you are using `pdftex`, then `bbold` should be in fact the correct choice, so then please explain why you would not prefer using it. If it's about the redefinition of `\mathbb` from `amssymb`: that can be easily taken care of.

Comment: You might also try `\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}` to switch to New Computer Modern.

Comment: You would not normally mix `unicode-math` with `amssymb`. It doesn’t cause an error, but `amssymb` will have no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$a\mathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

with `lualatex` yields

[image]

(The `a` is there just for the sake of comparison.)

Similarly, running `pdflatex` on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\begin{document}
$a\mathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The two results look quite identical, so I don't really understand your claim that

> I would prefer NOT to use the bbol, mathbbold, bbm, ... packages. The only package I've encountered so far that provides a nice rendering of the character I'm looking for is `unicode-math`.

In fact, the standard math font with `lualatex` and `xelatex` is Latin Modern Math, and its documentation states explicitly

> the double struck script is excerpted from Alan Jeffrey's bbold font

My guess is that your problem with loading `bbold` is that it overwrites the definition of `\mathbb` from `amssymb`. This can be easily circumvented by adapting the code of `bbold.sty` (it's just six lines of code)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\newcommand*{\boldone}{\mathbbold{1}}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{R}$    % that's still from amssymb
$\mathbbold{R}$ % that's from bbold
$\boldone$ % that's from bbold

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that once you use the symbol in a formula this solution will allocate a (possibly precious) math family; not an issue if you are not using lots of other fonts, but sometimes packages do things without you noticing. If you need only the `1`, you could alternatively define

```
\newcommand*{\boldone}{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}}
```

Comment: Using your very last solution, I get the following error (I'm using pdflatex with TeXstudio on Windows, with MikTeX): 

Font U/bbold/m/n/10.95=bbold11 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. $\boldone
\textfont 9 is undefined (character 1). $\boldone{1}$

Comment: I suppose I should add some files from bbold.zip to some directory, but I really wouldn't know where to put them. :/

Comment: @JilalJahangir Uhm, it works for me under TeXLive both under linux und windows. The error seems to suggest that your MikTeX installation is possibly not complete but I have no experience with MikTeX.

Comment: @JilalJahangir No, never try to put files manually somewhere. The MikTeX package manager should handle this kind of stuff. I'm searching for similar issues here on the site.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work (1) in TeXstudio, in a new document, using only your minimal working example above and (2) on Overleaf, in the actual document I needed the symbol for. TeXstudio produces a garbled, low-quality version of the character, while Overleaf renders it nicely.

Comment: @JilalJahangir Which version of MikTeX do you have? It might be possible that in old installations (or if you have installed something manually) the bitmap font is used. But I've tested this on three different machines now (admittedly, all with TeXLive) and I get always the same (good) result.

Comment: I'm using MikTeX 2.9. I checked and there were some package updates available, so I'm installing those now.

Comment: TeXstudio does manage to render your code inside my document now, but it still produces a pixelated version of the character. I've seen the exact same pixelated character in my QFT course notes, so I suppose it's not an uncommon problem.

Comment: @JilalJ I don't use MiKTeX, but do you have the [bbold-type1](https://miktex.org/packages/bbold-type1) package installed (in the MiKTeX package manager or whatever it's called)?

Comment: @frougon I didn't, but I do now and the character suddenly renders flawlessly! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help after wasting @campa's time. :-)

Comment: @frougon Oh, I thought that for some reason the bitmap fonts were being used but I didn't think that the type1 fonts were distributed as a separate package. And don't you worry: time spent delving into TeX's mechanisms is never wasted `:-D`