# Serif-style symbol for the set of real numbers

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to have a serif-style real number set symbol that looks like the one in the attached image; how can this be achieved? This is not possible using `$\mathbb{R}^n$`. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: `\mathds` from `dsfont`, as also described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26640/134144 could help.

Comment: @leandriis Yes, that seems to be the required shape.

Comment: @leandriis - This query does not appear to be a duplicate of an earlier posting on this site. Please go ahead and re-post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\mathds` from the `dsfont` package should result in the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\[\mathds{R}^{n}\]
\end{document}
```

### How to find it?

You can use a tool like [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or [Tex Match](https://github.com/zoeyfyi/TeX-Match) to figure it out.

[image: tex-match]