# On getting bold \mathtt and dsfont symbols using Minion Pro

Tags: fonts, xetex

I have the following setup to use `Mininon Pro`, in both text and math modes, in my `XeLaTeX`-based documents:

```
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Greek,Latin)[Numbers={Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}
```

However, I have the following issues:

(i) none of `$\bm{\mathtt{A}}$` (after loading `\usepackage{bm}`), `$\mathbf{\mathtt{A}}$`, and `$\boldsymbol{\mathtt{A}}$` make `$\mathtt{A}$` bold;

(ii) loading `\usepackage{dsfont}` and calling `\mathds{1}` does not yield the symbol illustrated in the Stefan Kotwittz's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Greek,Latin)[Numbers={Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}

\begin{document} 
$\bm{\mathtt{A}}$
$\mathbf{\mathtt{A}}$
$\boldsymbol{\mathtt{A}}$
$\mathds{1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: There’s a Minion Math font, for use with `unicode-math`, but it isn’t free.

Comment: @Davislor: Yes. I am aware of that. However, I am wondering whether there is a hack associated with free resources.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583600/61644) answer your second question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to get a bold teletype font in math mode is to use the `\text` commands from `amsmath`.

```
\newcommand\mathbftt[1]{\textnormal{\ttfamily\bfseries #1}}
```

To get the ds blackboard symbols, I would recommend

```
\usepackage[bb=dsserif]{mathalpha}
```

This enables `\mathbb` for double-struck, and `\mathbbb` for bold double-struck.

There is also a Minion Math font family for use with `unicode-math`, although it will cost you money.