# Why \mathbb{1} looking weird?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, overleaf, amssymb

I am writing a paper on overleaf where I use the prime indicator function, which is 0 when its input is not a prime and 1 otherwise. I have seen it been written as a 1 with the same font as sets like the integers and reals. So I thought using the `\mathbb` command would write it in the proper format. However, `\mathbb{1}` doesn’t give a one at all, it gives lines written weirdly. Here is a picture:

[image]

(I apologize for the blurry picture as I am on a phone right now) The packages I am using are Amsmath and Amssymb. When I put a Z in `\mathbb` I get what I want, but it does not work for 1 for some reason.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters

Comment: Welcome! If you need further help, please provide code for a minimal document which we can compile to reproduce the problem, but likely the characters are just missing. (The log should tell you this.)

Comment: I will add this, I appreciate that. The first comment solves my issue but technically doesn’t answer the question exactly. Also the log did not say anything about that.

Comment: You could also load the `dsfont` package and write `\mathds{1}`. (I suppose "ds" is short for "double-struck".)

Comment: This has already been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set). In short, there is no symbol for "1" in the `\mathbb` font, so you need a workaround.

Comment: The symbol that you get seems to be `\nVdash` (not double vertical, dash). If you are fine with using unicode fonts (with xelatex or lualatex), then many fonts such as NewCM, LM, Stix2 provide with double-struck 1.

Answer (score 15):

You want the explanation. OK, here it is.

Letters and digits are assigned math class 7, which means the same as class 0 (ordinary symbols) as far as spacing is concerned, but the letter or digit is taken from the math font corresponding to the current math group (math family, in plain TeX parlance).

Thus `\mathit{1}` or `\mathbf{1}` will choose the character at the slot `0x31` (hexadecimal, 49 in decimal) of the font assigned at startup to the “math italic” or “math bold”. This also works for `\mathcal{1}` and `\mathbb{1}`, but the fonts used by `\mathcal` and `\mathbb` ***don't*** necessarily have a 1 at that slot and in most font setups only uppercase *letters* are supported for `\mathcal` and `\mathbb`. What you get from `\mathbb{1}` is quite unpredictable.

*Some* math fonts have extended support for `\mathcal` or `\mathbb` to cover the whole alphabet (uppercase and lowercase).

If you're happy with your current font setup, but need a double stroked 1, you can look for a font that supports it. For instance, `stix2` does

[image]

How can you get it in your document without loading `stix2`, which would completely change the document fonts?

You look into `stix2.sty` to find

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}  {symbols3}
```

Now we look for `symbols3`

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols3}      {LS1}{stix2bb}   {m} {n}
```

OK, now we look for the file `ls1stix2bb.fd`

```
\ProvidesFile{ls1stix2bb.fd}
[2018/04/02 v2.0.0-latex stix2 %
blackboard LS1 %
font definitions]
\DeclareFontFamily{LS1}{stix2bb}{\skewchar\font127 }

\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stix2bb}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathbb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stix2bb}{m}{it}{<-> stix2-mathbbit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stix2bb}{b}{n} {<->sub * stix2bb/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stix2bb}{b}{it}{<->sub * stix2bb/m/it}{}
\endinput
```

and we just need the first one. But we can avoid defining a font encoding, because we just need ASCII characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%% put this in your document preamble
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stix2bb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stix2bb}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathbb}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\indicator}{}{\text{\usefont{U}{stix2bb}{m}{n}1}}
%%%

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{A}+\indicator_{X}(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The symbol  is registered in Unicode table.
If you are using Unicode math, then you can use the symbol  directly or using a macro. For example, in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]
$$
\bye
```

or

```
\fontfam[lm]
$\bbchar 1$
\bye
```

If you are using classical TeX (wich doesn't support Unicode) then you will drown in problems. The reason is that there is no single font with all math characters (like in Unicode math) but the set of math symbols is composed of many fonts: typically 7 bit fonts with 128 characters in them and each of them has very specific encoding. This concept has no future.

And why `\mathbb{1}` in LaTeX doesn't report problem and prints something different than user expects? The `\mathbb` macro selects one of the 7 bit font (mentioned above) and this font has a special math symbol at the code slot of `1` character, no .

Answer (score 3):

We could invoke the blackboard numbers by `\mathbbold` as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}


\begin{document}
\huge
\begin{align*}
\mathbbold{0123456789}\\
\mathbb{ABCQR}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As above, we use blackboard numbers by `\mathbbold` and blackboard letters by `\mathbb` from `amsfonts` or `amssymb`. Note that such blackboard numbers are also included in the `mathbbol` package which also includes blackboard letters different from ones here, and which is included on both computers installing windows and macs.

Also, the `bbold` package in which the blackboard numbers and letters here are included, is included in `TeX Live 202X` while not in the `MacTeX`. So if you use `TeX Live` on computers installing windows, you could invoke the `bbold` package, and if you use `MacTeX` on macs, you could use the solution as above.

Comment: `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are unnecessary here

Comment: @Stephen You are right. I delete them.