# \mathbb{0} and \mathbb{1} without affecting \mathbb{R} and \mathbb{N}

Tags: fonts, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blackboard bold characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters)

I want to write the numbers 0 and 1 in mathbb mode (inside some blockmatrices). So far the best way that I found is to use the bbold package. I have two questions:

- I would like the other mathbb symbols (such as \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{N}) to look as usual; using the bbold package they look worse, in my opinion;
- Even for the numbers 0 and 1, I am not completely satisfied with the output. Is there an alternative to the bbold package?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/how-do-i-make-a-blackboard-1

Comment: thanks, I did find the answer to the first question in your link. Any hint for the second (although less important) question?