# How to only get the symbol \Eins from mathbbol?

Tags: symbols

I want to have a `\mathbb{1}` without affecting the usual appearance of `\mathbb{R}`.

I have tried the solutions given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3493/8323 but the only that works is the `\usepackage{mathbbol}` (I suspect a package clash somewhere). But it affects all the other "blackboarded" characters.

Is it possible?

---

More precisions:

- When I say "it affects all the other "blackboarded" characters", I mean the font of the "blackboard" changes. But the thing is I don't want to change all the "blackboarded"  character; I only want to add one.
- With other packages, it does not work: when I do `\mathds{1}` or `\mathbbm{1}` or, etc. the `1` is not doubled.

Apart from `\usepackage{mathbbol}`, the other packages I've tried are

```
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{mbboard}
```

Comment: Please post a MWE of what exactly rises your error.

Comment: If it is possible to help me with a solution without a MWE, it would be great. (I load a lot of packages)

Comment: But that's the purpose of an MWE, you're supposed to strip out the unnecessary packages and construct a minimal document for yourself

Comment: Yes I know! I'm telling that if it is possible to help me with a solution without a MWE, it would be great. Basically I'm asking how to extract a single symbol from a "font" package.

Comment: And a quick google search on the basic question results in this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple if you want the symbol at its natural height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Eins}{%
  \text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}%
}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{A}\Eins$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get equal height with some more work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bbold}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
 {
  <-5.5> s*[1.069] bbold5
  <5.5-6.5> s*[1.069] bbold6
  <6.5-7.5> s*[1.069] bbold7
  <7.5-8.5> s*[1.069] bbold8
  <8.5-9.5> s*[1.069] bbold9
  <9.5-11> s*[1.069] bbold10
  <11-15> s*[1.069] bbold12
  <15-> s*[1.069] bbold17
 }{}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Eins}{%
  \text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}1}%
}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{A}\Eins$

\end{document}
```

[image]