# Why can't my LaTeX find bbm font other than some specific size?

Tags: amsmath, fontsize, math-fonts, amssymb, blackboard

So, I'm using `bbm` package to extend the original `\mathbb{}` from `amssymb` to the non-capital-alphabet region. This works fine in the ordinary part. But, when I try to change the size of the math mode, then `LaTeX` told me that it don't find the corresponding font. The following is an **MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}
    % {\small$ \mathbbm{R1} $}
    $ \mathbbm{R1} $
    % {\large$ \mathbbm{R1} $}
    {\Large$ \mathbbm{R1} $}
    % {\LARGE$ \mathbbm{R1} $}
    % {\huge$ \mathbbm{R1} $}
    % {\Huge$ \mathbbm{R1} $}
\end{document}
```

Only the uncommented lines give me correct outputs. All commented lines give me fatal error that even PDF files will not pop out. I don't know why. The **`.log` files** for the error version all look like

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.11.16)  22 NOV 2021 02:00
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
L3 programming layer <2021-11-12> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count183
\c@chapter=\count184
\c@section=\count185
\c@subsection=\count186
\c@subsubsection=\count187
\c@paragraph=\count188
\c@subparagraph=\count189
\c@figure=\count190
\c@table=\count191
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/10/15 v2.17l AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen139
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen140
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2021/08/26 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count193
\leftroot@=\count194
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count195
\DOTSCASE@=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box50
\strutbox@=\box51
\big@size=\dimen141
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count197
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count198
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count199
\dspbrk@lvl=\count266
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count267
\column@=\count268
\maxfields@=\count269
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen142
\alignsep@=\dimen143
\tagshift@=\dimen144
\tagwidth@=\dimen145
\totwidth@=\dimen146
\lineht@=\dimen147
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2938.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2939.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty
Package: bbm 1999/03/15 V 1.2 provides fonts for set symbols - TH
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbbm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/bbm/m/n --> U/bbm/bx/n on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbbmss' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/bbmss/m/n --> U/bbmss/bx/n on input line 35.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-10-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count270
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 740.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 741.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 741.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+bbm on input line 741.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/ubbm.fd
File: ubbm.fd 1999/03/15 V 1.2 Font definition for bbm font - TH
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1741 strings out of 478371
 25029 string characters out of 5848512
 315316 words of memory out of 5000000
 19875 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 410920 words of font info for 60 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 54i,5n,62p,212b,153s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 </Users/tianluoqi/Library/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm/bbm12.720pk> </Users/tianluoqi/Library/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm/bbm10.600pk>
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file bbm9): Font bbm9 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

And in the **terminal**, the outputs are

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
L3 programming layer <2021-11-12>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/bbm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbm-macros/ubbm.fd) [1{/usr/local
/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ) </U
sers/tianluoqi/Library/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/bbm/bbm12.
720pk> </Users/tianluoqi/Library/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/
bbm/bbm10.600pk>
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 bbm9
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for bbm9.
mktexpk: perhaps bbm9 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file bbm9): Font bbm9 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The only difference is that here `bbm9` is for `\small` and correspondingly we would find others if we want to use other font sizes.

But, I have checked that all those claimed missing fonts all exist in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/bbm`. (BTW, if that is helpful, I'm using MacOS 10.15.7)

[image]

Comment: Probably unrelated but did remember that with very few exceptions `hyperret` needs to be the **last** package loaded

Comment: Additionally, do remember that AFAIK bnm is not at scalable font. It's font settings might simply not apply to large sizes. (not at pc do cannot test code)

Comment: you are showing the tfm files but that is just the font metrics, it is the pk file that tex can not find (or make) do you have `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/bbm/bbm9.mf`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry that I mistake the correct folder. I have checked that I also have those files correctly in the folder and have updated the screenshot in the question. BTW, I'm very new to font but I really want to know more font-related computer knowledge (not necessarily constrained in the font in LaTeX). For example, what is the difference between tmf and pk file. Any book or reference recommendation?

Comment: @daleif Yes, I'm aware of that. That is my mis. Actually, this error has nothing with `hyperref`. Even if I don't load `hyperref` this error still exist. I will update my code.

Comment: the tfm file just has the metrics, so basically four numbtes per character height/width/depth/italic-correction traditionally that was all tex needed to determine the dvi file, then the dvi driver wiuld need the pk (packed bitmap) files with the actual shapes.  But pdftex acts as its own "back end" so needs both the tfm and pk files. the pk should be made on demand by calling maketexpk  using teh metafont (`.mf`) source files.

Comment: @daleif So, do you have any other recommendations on how to extend the original `\mathbb{}` from `amssymb` to the non-capital-alphabet region? Actually I begin to use `bbm` after reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/how-do-i-make-a-blackboard-1). Among those packages listed there, `bbm` seems to be newest and I hope that this means that the chance of it still being maintained is higher, so I choose to use this.

Comment: metafont fonts (if they have not been converted to type1) are bitmap fonts in the pdf so don't react well to being shown at different zoom levels. More modern packages such as stix2 provide blackboard bold in uppper and lower case using scalable fonts

Comment: What exactly do you need from bbm? I normally do not use it as it is not a scalable vector font. I see no need for a bb version of R1. I would just use bold (mathbf)

Comment: `mktexpk: perhaps bbm9 is missing from the map file.`  you could update the map file with `updmap-sys`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems that `updmap-sys` is not helpful for me either. So, I choose to avoid this problem by using stix2 that you mentioned