# How to use \bigtimes without pain

Tags: fonts, symbols, macros, packages

I've been fighting with `mathabx` lately and it's not really worth my time, so I tried switching to `MnSymbol` which also modifies some of my regular symbols. Is the best solution just to make my own operator of times that's larger than normal and what's the best way to do this? Or is there a library that adds the various variable sized symbols not covered in the `amsmath` packages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be done in a similar way as I suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters/3260#3260) to a question about blackboard bold characters: Find and copy the relevant lines from the `mathabx` files.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigtimes}{1}{mathx}{"91}
\begin{document}
$\bigtimes\limits_{j=1}^n X_j$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used:

```
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\bigtimes}{\vartimes}
```

This solution I found at http://matheraum.de/forum/Kartesisches_Produkt_in_Latex/t278084.

Comment: This is indeed a quick and easy solution, thx. `\bigtimes` in `stmaryrd` is a bit narrow and, thus, looks not as nice as the smaller LaTeX `\times`. At least, `stmaryrd` seems to be one of the few symbol packages that does not lead to the usual conflicts when used with AMS packages.

Answer (score 3):

Is using Xe/LuaLaTeX with `unicode-math` an option? There you can just use `\bigtimes` (or nearly any other conceivable math symbol) without having to worry about any additional packages or fonts.