# How to generate the following symbol(s) in book class?

Tags: symbols

Is it possible to generate symbol(s) like to following in `book`-class

[image]

The image has been produced by the following code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

$\varprod_{i=1}^n A_i$

$$\varprod_{i=1}^n A_i$$

\end{document}
```

but I don't want to use `kpfonts`.

Comment: Both alternatives listed in the answer below are available in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)...

Comment: all the suggestions given result in a change of the entire symbol set.  this isn't a reasonable alternative.  see [How to use \bigtimes without pain](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4955/579) for a more limited approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Other fonts

### Package `mathabx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\centering
$\bigtimes_{i=1}^n A_i$
\[ \bigtimes_{i=1}^n A_i \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result mathabx]

### Packages `txfonts/pxfonts`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
\centering
$\varprod_{i=1}^n A_i$
\[ \varprod_{i=1}^n A_i \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result txfonts]

### Package `MnSymbol`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\centering
$\bigtimes_{i=1}^n A_i$
\[ \bigtimes_{i=1}^n A_i \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result MnSymbol]

## Import math characters

The packages listed in the previous section also change other math symbols.
But it is also possible to use math symbols of other fonts by defining
math alphabets. However, keep in mind that the number of math alphabets is a limited resource.

### `\varprod` of `kpfonts`

```
\documentclass{book}

% Use \varprod of package kpfonts
\DeclareSymbolFont{KPlargesymbolsA}{U}{jkpexa}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{KPlargesymbolsA}{bold}{U}{jkpexa}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varprod}{\mathop}{KPlargesymbolsA}{16}

\begin{document}

\centering
$\varprod_{i=1}^n A_i$

\[\varprod_{i=1}^n A_i\]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Can the same codes be used for `book`-class also?

Comment: @user170039 Yes.

Comment: But using the same code in `book` changes some other symbols also. What should I do to prevent this?

Comment: @user170039 See updated answer.