# Best way to typeset the identity operator, or unit?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blackboard bold characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters)

I have seen the unit (or identity operator) typeset via

```
\newcommand{\unit}{1\!\!1}
```

Is this really the best way to get a double-stroke 1? The obvious guess, `\mathbb{1}`, does not work.

Or is the use of a double-stroke 1 (rather than "Id" or just a simple "1") for this purpose frowned upon?

Comment: I would highly recommend `\usepackage{bbm}` and `\newcommand\idop{\bbm 1}`.

Comment: This can be confusing.

Answer (score 11):

Try `\mathds` from the [`dsfont` package](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/doublestroke/dsdoc.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\(\mathds{1}\)

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is:

[image]