# What symbol is this?

Tags: symbols

[image: Symbol]

I need the command to display this symbol in LaTeX or, at least, its name.

I guess it’s from some kind of a mathematical or informatics discipline. I saw it in article called “[A comparison of collapsed Bayesian methods for probabilistic finite automata](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10994-013-5410-3#page-1)”. Actually, I have no idea what it is all about: I just started learning LaTeX and I have to copy this article. This symbol is used just as if it is a casual letter like *x* or *y*. The line which includes it is,

> Input : a(this symbol), N, BurnInTime, SamplingNum, Period

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Where did you see this symbol, what does it mean, what field of study does it belong to?

Comment: I have never seen this symbol before. Have you checked the comprehensive symbol list already? http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: I guess it's from some kind of a math or informatic discipline, saw it in article called "A comparison of collapsed Bayesian methods
for probabilistic finite automata". Actually, i have no idea what is it all about, i just started learning LaTeX and i have to copy this article. This symbol is used just like it's a casual letter like "x" or "y". Line with it looks like "Input : a(this symvol), N, BurnInTime, SamplingNum, Period

Comment: If that article is made in LaTeX too, chances are good, that the symbol is available too

Comment: the article is in [*Machine Learning* (2014) **96**:155-188](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10994-013-5410-3#page-1), published by springer, so maybe it was prepared in latex.  unfortunately, only the abstract and introduction are posted at the link, and they don't show the symbol (which i've never seen before either).

Comment: try http://detexify.kirelabs.org/ or look a http://arxiv.org/ for an article containing this symbol and than under other formats->download source to view the .tex code

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet)

Comment: @MartinSchröder If it is not possible to find via tools in that question we tend to leave these open, with emphasis on **tend to**

Comment: @MartinSchröder -- that's a great question and answers, but not one of them addresses the method that was needed to identify this particular symbol.  if someone would add to those answers the method for checking what fonts are used in a known pdf file, that would improve that question *almost* to the point where this could be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @samcarter [detexify.kirelabs.org](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/) didn't find the letter (or symbol) and that I tried to draw it as best I could.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To me this looks like a blackboard bold lowercase *a*.  Specifically, it looks like the lowercase *a* from the [bbold](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-26732.html) font.

[image: bbold font]

For blackboard bold capitals you can use the `\mathbb` macro provided by the `amsfonts` or `amssymb` packages.  But `$\mathbb{a}$` gives a backwards *G*.

Instead, you need to load the whole `bbold` font.  Here's a quick snippet to do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbold}{bbold}

\begin{document}
$\mathbbold{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image: bbold a]

See also [Blackboard bold characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters)

Comment: good sleuthing.  i would *never* have gotten this without help.  i'm much more accustomed to the shape shown in the unicode charts at U+1D552.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks.  It was a hunch and some quick googling.  Knowing that it was used as a variable instead of a binary operation or relation was a hint that it might be a letter of some kind.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang i can't get a `a` letter with good quality, if i run your code i get a `a` pixelled, very different to [this test](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/fonts/bbold-type1/test.pdf). If you can help me!

Comment: @skpblack: Hm, it's possible your installation doesn't have the fonts at the size you want?  What does the log file say?

Comment: Something like `LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+bbold on input line 9.

("C:\Program Files\LaTeX\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\ubbold.fd"
File: ubbold.fd 1996/01/01 Blackboard Bold Font Definition File (jk)
) [1`

Comment: @skpblack: Debugging font installations are not my expertise, so to get more exposure to your problem I think you should ask a separate question, linking back to this one.

Comment: Simply, do you have the `bold-type1` package. That might explain.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks, i can solve my problem installing the `bbm` package. After of this i believe that a missed fonts were installed. I did not even include it in the preamble and your code works well.

Comment: @skpblack: I think the fonts used by the `bbm` package are in the blackboard bold shape, but not the same as the `bbold` font.

Answer (score 3):

I think Matthew is right, there is the `pdffonts` output from the article Barbara linked to

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
Times-Roman                          Type 1C           yes no  no     763  0
Times-Bold                           Type 1C           yes no  no     764  0
MTSYB                                Type 1C           yes no  yes    765  0
MTSYN                                Type 1C           yes no  yes    771  0
MarVoSym                             Type 1C           yes no  yes    778  0
Times-Italic                         Type 1C           yes no  no     459  0
MTMI                                 Type 1C           yes no  yes    463  0
BBOLD5                               Type 1C           yes no  yes    480  0
BBOLD7                               Type 1C           yes no  yes    475  0
MTEX                                 Type 1C           yes no  yes    470  0
Courier                              Type 1C           yes no  no     491  0
MSBM10                               Type 1C           yes no  yes    500  0
```