# Loading amsfonts after mathbbol does not reset \mathbb

Tags: math-mode, amsfonts

I'm using the `mathbbol` package so I can use `\mathbb` with Greek and lower-case letters.  The [package documentation](http://web.mit.edu/newtex/doc/latex/jknappen/mathbbol.rme) states

> Without options, the following commands are defined:
>
> - \mathbb{A}  to produce blackbord bold A. All upper and lowercase latin  letters are accessible this way. It overwrites AMS-LaTeX's 
>     \mathbb (and can be overwritten if you load amsfonts after mathbbol)

I am not seeing this functionality

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

%$\mu = \bbnu(a,b,c)$
$\mathbb{K}$

\end{document}
```

Specifically:

- With the `mathbbol` package commented out, `\mathbb{K}` prints the `amsfonts` verion (with 
  serifs)
- With `mathbbol`, `\mathbb{K}` prints the `mathbbol` verion (without 
  serifs), even though `amsfonts` is loaded afterwards

How can I keep the normal `amsfonts` versions for upper-case `\mathbb{}` but also add the lower-case and Greek letters from `mathbbol`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply add the lines

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbl}{bbold}
```

in your preamble and use `\mathbbl` instead of `\mathbb` for lowercase latin letters.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbl}{bbold}

\begin{document}

$\mu = \bbnu(a,b,c)$

$\mathbb{K}$

$\mathbbl{k}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason why simply loading `amsfonts` doesn't work is that in `amsfonts.sty` you have

```
\@ifundefined{mathbb}{%
    \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}%
}{}
```

which means to set the `\mathbb` alphabet to `AMSb` only if it has not been defined.

But it has been already defined by `mathbbol` to be

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{bbold}
```

so it doesn't work without that additional line.

Comment: It  works well. However, it conflicts with the \section{$a$} when there is the math sign in section. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I ran into some very strange behavior for commands like \mathbb{\Delta} when using this suggestion. I just posted [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661388/mathbbol-displays-incorrect-symbols) explaining the issue.

Comment: I found, though, that the approach in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495/788) worked for me.