Is there any way to write $\mathds{\Delta}$?
Usually \mathds does not work on Greek letters but I was wondering if there is some package that enables it.

You can try the bbold package, it supports at least a few Greek letters.

Yes I tried that, but it changes the mathbb package. I was looking for something different.

Please specify what this "something different" is exactly =) Maybe you want to extend your question and add the use case, so that it is more clear what you're after. Note that there are already some related Q&A on this site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=mathbb+greek

Sorry for not being clear in the previous comment. I don't want to change the usual \mathbb command, but want a \mathbb or \mathds version of \Delta. Using bbold package, the entire \mathbb command changes and makes the notation different, which I do not prefer.

Did you follow the like I provided? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234451/47927 for a possible solution.

The result is, in my opinion, suboptimal. Anyway, you can try with the Delta from bbold.
I redefined the font description to allow any size and to magnify the font that, at natural width, is too short.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont} % really ugly...

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bbold}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbold}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> s*[1.05] bbold5
  <5.5-6.5> s*[1.05] bbold6
  <6.5-7.5> s*[1.05] bbold7
  <7.5-8.5> s*[1.05] bbold8
  <8.5-9.5> s*[1.05] bbold9
  <9.5-11> s*[1.05] bbold10
  <11-16> s*[1.05] bbold12
  <16-> s*[1.05] bbold17
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bbDelta}{}{%
  \mathord{\text{\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}\symbol{"01}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\Delta\ne\bbDelta\ne\mathds{R}$

\end{document}



You could using also mathbbol with the option bbgreekl.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bbDelta}\mathord{bbold}{"01}

\begin{document}
Let $f(x) = \bbDelta x^2$, hence $f'(x) = 2\Delta x$.
\end{document}


