# Is mathbb an abbreviation for something?

Tags: meaning

What does mathbb stand for? Is it short for something else?  I searched online and couldn't find a definition, only information about usage.

Comment: the `bb` in `\mathbb` stands for "blackboard bold".  the `\math` indicates that this is a font/symbol to be used only in math.

Comment: It stands for math blackboard.   See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name part `bb` of `\mathbb` is short for `blackboard`.

See also question ["What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/16967)
and some information from the Wikipedia article ["Blackboard bold"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold).