# Looking for a specific font package (if it exists)

Tags: fonts

Is there a blackboard bold font package corresponding to the code below?

```
\mathrm{I\!R}
\mathrm{I\!N}
```

[image]

Hopefully, said package would include a symbol for the integers. I really like how these symbols look, much more than the standard `amsmath` ones. Knuth just writes the first symbol in the TeXbook without mentioning anything else.

Comment: Now what's exactly the issue with the `amsmath` ones? It would be nice, if you could specify your requirements a bit further.

Comment: @TeXnician I don't have technical requirements - that's why I didn't include technical criticisms in the body of my post. My issue is strictly one of taste. I feel like the `amsmath` blackboard bold fonts look busy, whereas the plain `\mathbf{R}` looks a little spartan for my tastes. The symbols in my post seem to have the "just right" quality.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters) help?

Comment: @occamsrazor I've never seen such a font (but I dislike that appearance, so didn't really look deeply).

Answer (score 4):

What about `\mathds` from `dsfont` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \mathds{R} \quad \mathds{N} \quad \mathds{I} \quad \mathds{Z}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]