# Error when using blackboard bold fonts to produce indicator function

Tags: fonts, luatex, libertine, blackboard, mathbb

I have a weird problem. It all started when I got problems when trying to create the indicator function with a double stroke `1` using `\mathbb{1}` which within the Visual Studio reads as using 'Latex Workshop' extension [image: image showing two]

The image shows the number two, but the same case is true for the number one.
In the pdf however it looks like this
[image]
Here I also tried some other numbers as well. I think it has something to do with the Libertine font package that I have loaded, but then how come the `R` appear the correct way in the pdf?

Any thoughts or tips on how to solve this is much appreciated:)

Comment: the standard ams mathbb does not have digits at all

Comment: Might seem so, but I cant get it to work with other packages that provide digits
such as `\usepackage{ bbold }` or `\usepackage{ dsfont }` ://

Comment: Looks like you've seen [fonts - Blackboard bold characters - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters) (it's always good to link top questions you've come across while researching for an answer) -- give a MWE with one of those then.

Comment: no one can debug a screenshot of code especially if it does not show the relevant code, make a small complete example as a text code block in your question

Comment: Your used maths font may not support all these. Note that the preview in LaTeX-Workshop extension does not use LaTeX itself.